# How to change an asp c# public variable from js?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, web

I'm working in Microsoft visual web developer 2010 express with aspx project. And I'm trying to change a public variable from the c# code in the js code.
But I couldn't find how. can anyone help me? 
thx.

**So I have this var in my c# code**

```
public partial class ASPX_Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 public bool check = false;
}
```

**And I want to change it in my js function.**

```
function myfun() {
//here I want to change check to true
}
```

I thought about creating an invisible asp obj and change its value. But I think it's not the right solution... 
Is there any other accepted solutions?

Comment: I am not sure it can be done. After all C# runs server side and to my best knowledge it is not transpiled to JS.

Comment: yes, but I would like to run a javascript check and only if it's true to run the c# code. so is there a way to run it only if the javascript function returned true? that's why I thought about changing a public var... @GrayCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp.net language C# is a server language thats executed before the page is loaded in the browser and can only be accessed when reloading the page changing the value for this page would demand a postback.

Javascript is clientscript which is a language the runs on the browser.
If you want javascript to communicate with your serverscript I advice to use Ajax.

Jquery has easy to use ajax options.
Here is an example on how to use Jquery Ajax.
[Jquery ajax Method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/)